# How can I stamp every page of a pdf except the first one?

Tags: pdf, pdftk

I have two PDF files; one is a document and the other is a single page containing a graphic. So far I have been using pdftk to stamp the graphic onto the document like so:

```
pdftk document.pdf stamp graphic.pdf output.pdf
```

It has worked fine. However I have recently added a title page which I do not want to be stamped, and I cannot see an option in pdftk to skip the first page.

I already tried to separate the title page into it's own document, and use pdftk to merge them after stamping, but my document has bookmarks which are completely destroyed when pdftk does a merge.

Does anyone have any suggestions? All I really need is an equivalent to pdftk's stamp command that lets me specify a page range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't seem to see anything that allows you to select a range (Seems like a deficiency, you should put in a feature request)

However this seems like a decent workaround, from the man-page:

> multistamp < multistamp PDF filename | - | PROMPT > Same as the stamp
>   operation, but applies each page of the stamp PDF to the corresponding
>   page of the input PDF. If the input PDF has more pages than the stamp
>   PDF, then the final stamp page is repeated across these remaining
>   pages in the input PDF.

So create a pdf with a blank first page and on the second page put your stamp. Then run that file using multistamp

Comment: `multibackground` and `multistamp` added to `pdftk` in version 1.43 (Sept 2010)

Comment: Ingenious. It worked like a charm :)